# Trying to add an onItemSelectedListener to a spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

I'm trying to add an onItemSelectedListener to a spinner. I've looked at other questions on here with similar problems and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting an error when it runs, but the toast I'm trying to create doesn't pop up.

I've got a spinner that's populated with different age options and it should pop up in a toast in which one is selected. I've tried else ifs, else ifs, and I'm not sure if I'm calling it wrong or if I need to reintroduce a form of control flow. At this stage I'd be grateful for any help.

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class secActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec);
        onItemSelected();
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int     position, long id)
    {

        Toast.makeText(secActivity.this, "You have clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }   
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `Spinner` object? IS this your complete code?

Comment: @PrerakSola It's here: `import android.widget.Spinner;` ;)

Comment: Ah... okay... Since when did android development became this robust... ;)

Comment: @PrerakSola In Sci-Fi movies, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how spinner can be used

```
// Reference the spinner    
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Set spinner onItemClickListener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(secActivity.this, "You have clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
        });
```

Comment: when I do that it's giving me errors on onItemSelectedListener as it can't resolve it, but it's also saying my import for it is unused. When I try and implement onItemSelectedListener instead, it says I must declare my class as absract or implement different parameters for OnItemSelected.

Comment: Kindly go through this:- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm